# Base class overload

Tags: c#

I have a base class for application's entities:

```
public class LadderEntityBase : ICloneable
{
    public Guid PK { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }

    public object Clone()
    {
        return this.MemberwiseClone();
    }
}
```

Then two classes derive from it, with same functionality overload, which allows to create those classes with or without PK (Guid) parameter. If PK parameter omitted - new Guid will be created:

```
public class Order : LadderEntityBase
{
    public Order() : this(Guid.NewGuid())
    {
    }

    public Order(Guid guid)
    {
        this.PK = guid;
    }

    public string OrderFrom { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Parcel : LadderEntityBase
{
    public Parcel() : this(Guid.NewGuid())
    {
    }

    public Parcel(Guid guid)
    {
        this.PK = guid;
    }

    public string SentTo { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to move Order's and Parcel's both constructors into the base class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe its as far as you can go. Move all logic in base class and leave just base calls in inherited

```
public class LadderEntityBase : ICloneable
{
    public LadderEntityBase(Guid pk)
    {
        PK = pk;
    }

    public LadderEntityBase() : this(Guid.NewGuid())
    {
    }

    public Guid PK { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }

    public object Clone()
    {
        return this.MemberwiseClone();
    }
}

public class Order : LadderEntityBase
{
    public Order() : base()
    {
    }

    public Order(Guid guid) : base(guid)
    {
    }

    public string OrderFrom { get; set; }
}

public class Parcel : LadderEntityBase
{
    public Parcel() : base()
    {
    }

    public Parcel(Guid guid) : base(guid)
    {
    }

    public string SentTo { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the PK on Base class itself and then use base keyword to set the GUID(if you want different GUIDs for both derived classes).

```
public class LadderEntityBase : ICloneable
    {
        public Guid PK { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
        public LadderEntityBase(Guid guid)
        {
            this.PK = guid;

        }

        public object Clone()
        {
            return this.MemberwiseClone();
        }
    }

    public class Order : LadderEntityBase
    {
        public Order() : this(Guid.NewGuid())
        {
        }

        public Order(Guid guid) : base(guid)
        {

        }

        public string OrderFrom { get; set; }
    }

    public class Parcel : LadderEntityBase
    {
        public Parcel() : this(Guid.NewGuid())
        {
        }

        public Parcel(Guid guid) :base( guid)
        {

        }

        public string SentTo { get; set; }
    }
```